# How does my linux OS make so quickly sign in process?

Tags: shell-script, hashsum, whois

I have written this shell script to test sha-516 hash password string :

```
myhash='$6$nxIRLUXhRQlj$t29nGt1moX3KcuFZmRwUjdiS9pcLWpqKhAY0Y0bp2pqs3fPrnVAXKKbLfyZcvkkcwcbr2Abc8sBZBXI9UaguU.' #Which is created by mkpasswd for test

i=0
while [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
do
        testpass=$(mkpasswd -m sha-512 "test")
        i=$[ $i + 1 ]
        if [[ "$testpass" == "$myhash" ]];
                then
                        echo -e "found\n"
                        break
        else
                echo -e "$myhash /= $testpass :-> $i Testing....\n"
        fi

done
```

After running **216107** numbers loop test I never found match.But in case of my linux OS(Ubuntu) system make so quickly match sign in credentials.My question is Why do I not get the same so quickly?

Comment: Your OS generates 200000+ passwords automatically and tries them one by one?

Comment: I think you have a fundamental misconception about signing on. Think a little bit what you do when you log on. Do you provide a SHA512 string? Or do you provide a password? What do you think the system does with this password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A password hash (like what you put in `myhash`) contains some metadata indicating which hash function is used and with what parameters such as cost, a salt, and the output of the hash function. In the modern Unix password hash format, the parts are separated by `$`:

- `6` indicates the [Unix iterated SHA-512 method](https://akkadia.org/drepper/SHA-crypt.txt) (a design that is similar, but not identical, to [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)).
- There are no parameters, so the cost factor is the default value.
- `nxIRLUXhRQlj` is the salt.
- `t29nGt1moX3KcuFZmRwUjdiS9pcLWpqKhAY0Y0bp2pqs3fPrnVAXKKbLfyZcvkkcwcbr2Abc8sBZBXI9UaguU.` is the expected output.

Each time you run `mkpasswd -m sha-512`, it creates a password hash with a random salt. So each run of this command produces a different output.

When you type your password, the system calculates `iterated_sha512(default_cost, "nxIRLUXhRQlj", typed_password)` and checks whether the output is `"t29nGt1moX3KcuFZmRwUjdiS9pcLWpqKhAY0Y0bp2pqs3fPrnVAXKKbLfyZcvkkcwcbr2Abc8sBZBXI9UaguU."`.

What your program is doing is different: you generate a random salt, then compare it plus the output of the password hashing function to `myhash`. This only matches if you've happened to generate the same salt, which has a negligible probability (your computer isn't going to generate the same salt twice in your lifetime). But you don't need to guess the salt: it's right there in the password hash.

Recommended reading: [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords)

Answer (score 3):

`mkpasswd` requires also a **salt** otherwise it generates one for you every time you run it. If you deconstruct the original string by using **$** as separators then you see [hashing method](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/crypt.5.html) **6** and `nxIRLUXhRQlj` as salt.

If we add the salt to `mkpasswd` when running then you get the correct result in one go.

```bsh
$ mkpasswd -m sha-512 "test" "nxIRLUXhRQlj"
$6$nxIRLUXhRQlj$t29nGt1moX3KcuFZmRwUjdiS9pcLWpqKhAY0Y0bp2pqs3fPrnVAXKKbLfyZcvkkcwcbr2Abc8sBZBXI9UaguU.
```

Using a [salt](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) prevents against the [rainbow table attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) as it adds a random part to the password before hashing it.